# jquery how can I convert a json object to javascript array for jqplot

Tags: jquery

I'm using jqplot to generate charts.  It works fine when I define the source data in javascript:

```
  var goog2 = [["6/22/2009", 425.32],["6/8/2009", 424.84],["5/26/2009", 417.23]];
```

I'm now trying to pull the data from a server side web method:

```
  <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Test() As String
    Return ("[[""6/22/2009"",425.32],[""7/22/2009"",429.32]];")
End Function
```

No matter what I do to the returned object I can't seem to get it into the format that's required.

```
   function DoAction2(cat) {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "AjaxTest.aspx/Test",
              data: "{cat:" + cat + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(msg) {
              alert(msg.d);
                  var d = msg.d;
                  plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [d])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the returned string from your `Test()` function the entire response?

In your JS you're asking for `msg.d`, but there's no `d` element in your JSON structure (as shown).

Also, the trailing semicolon shouldn't be there.  It's not [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Yes the returned string is the entire response.  If I drop the semi colon, will the returned object be treated the same as the javascript variable declared client side to test?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but you just want `msg`, not `msg.d`.

Comment: thanks, I've changed it to msg and [[6/22/2009,425.32],[7/22/2009,429.32]] server side but get an error saying theres no data to plot

Comment: You took out the quote marks? (they are needed for the date fields)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're returning the exact structure you need from the server, yes? If so, then I don't understand your attempt to access 'msg.d' in your success function.  'msg' is your data structure...

Also, I have no idea what lang you're using on the server side so I don't know much about its syntax, but that does not appear to be properly escaping quotes/etc in order to produce a valid JSON response.

Comment: In some languages (particular those with a BASIC heritage) you have to use a pair of double quotes to obtain one double quote inside a string.